# Pandas: create a new column that alternates between two columns

Tags: python, database, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with 3 columns named timestamp, A and B. I want to make a new dataframe in which I have Timestamp and a single column C. Elements of C are as follows:

```
C[1] = A[1]
C[2]= B[1]
C[3] = A[2]
C[4] = B[2]
```

The timestamp entry will be the same for same rows of previous dataframe.
Whats the most convenient way to achieve the above operation?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html

Comment: I see my solution does not work, because unanccepted. What is problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index('timestamp').stack().rename_axis(('dates', 'cols')).reset_index(name='C')
print (df1)
       dates cols  C
0 2012-01-01    A  2
1 2012-01-01    B  8
2 2012-01-02    A  3
3 2012-01-02    B  9
4 2012-01-03    A  5
5 2012-01-03    B  1
```

Or [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), but order of values is different:

```
df1 = df.melt(id_vars='timestamp', var_name='cols', value_name='C')
#pandas bellow 0.20.1
#df1 = pd.melt(df, id_vars='timestamp', var_name='cols', value_name='C')
print (df1)
   timestamp cols  C
0 2012-01-01    A  2
1 2012-01-02    A  3
2 2012-01-03    A  5
3 2012-01-01    B  8
4 2012-01-02    B  9
5 2012-01-03    B  1
```